# Is it ok to list undergraduate education at the bottom of my resume, while listing my graduate education at the top?

Tags: resume, united-states

I want to put my recent graduate school education (completed May 2017) and teaching experience at the top of my resume, and then followed by my industry work experiences prior to grad school.  Then, towards the bottom of my resume, I would list my undergraduate college education.  I like it this way because at the top of my resume I would have the most desirable / relevant information -- I tried putting my graduate and undergraduate education together at the top of my resume, and it just seemed weird, because of the fairly big gap in graduation dates.

Is this ok to do?  Or is there a rule that says that *all* education should be together in one section?

Comment: Putting all your education on one place is the norm you can always add your degrees after your Name eg - Tommy Atkins BSc, MSc/MEng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this ok to do?

### Yes

In the situation outlined, your approach seems perfectly reasonable to me, for the exact reason you stated:  The most **relevant** information is at the top of your resume.  Do your best to make sure all content on your resume is as *relevant as it can be*.

There are *no hard and fast rules* in regards to how to layout your resume, and there are tons of online example you can review.

Comment: Almost completely agree - but I'd say that _all_ information in a resume should be relevant (and therefore no irrelevant information should be there in any order) - in order of most recent.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to do so, it's usually **preferable** to keep things together, and I would suggest that if you do it this way, you make a different header such as

> **ADDITIONAL EDUCATION**
>
> Attended the university of Widgetry, Bachelors in Widget design

or something like that.